# Можно ли задать форматирование для всех элементов, используя распаковку списка?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим у меня есть список `a=[1.0002,2.0003,4.0005]`, можно ли получить вывод типа `1.0 2.0 4.0` используя `print(*a)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = [1.2323232, 2.234343434, 3.23232323]
print(*[f"{x:.2f}" for x in a])
```

> 1.23 2.23 3.23

Answer (score 1):

Кажется я нашел решение, оно не совсем изящное, но все же решение: 
`print(*np.around(np.array(a), decimals=1))` 
Output 
`1.0 2.0 4.0`

Comment: Это как из пушки по воробьям